# pip install from Bitbucket fail

Tags: python, pip, bitbucket

I have a Bitbucket repository, and I need use this repository for a project, when I try to download from Bitbucket the following error occur.

```
 pip install git+https://xxxxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxxx/project.git             
Collecting git+https://paulohperes@bitbucket.org/paulohperes/snmp.git
  Cloning https://paulohperes@bitbucket.org/paulohperes/snmp.git to /private/var/folders/zt/k2g_4ksj5gg8517c2fdp1npm0000gn/T/pip-uxd3i1wu-build
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/zt/k2g_4ksj5gg8517c2fdp1npm0000gn/T/pip-uxd3i1wu-build/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/zt/k2g_4ksj5gg8517c2fdp1npm0000gn/T/pip-uxd3i1wu-build/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '…/setup.py'
```

I.e., you're trying to build a repository that's not a Python package and isn't pip-installable.

Hard to say more without looking into the code.